# How can I vary a shape's alpha with Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, alpha

I have the following code that uses Tkinter to create a window and draw shapes on a canvas inside it.

```
from Tkinter import *

class Example(Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        self.parent = parent 
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):

        self.parent.title("Colors")
        self.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)

        canvas = Canvas(self)

        canvas.create_oval(10, 10, 80, 80, outline="red", fill="green", width=2)
        canvas.create_oval(110, 10, 210, 80, outline="#f11", fill="#1f1", width=2)
        canvas.create_rectangle(20, 50, 300, 100, outline="black", fill="red", width=2)

        canvas.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = Tk()
    ex = Example(root)
    root.geometry("400x400+100+100") # WIDTHxHEIGHT+X+Y
    root.mainloop()
```

The rectangle sits on top of the two ovals.  Is there any way that I can make the rectangle partially transparent (so the ovals' outlines can be seen)?

Comment: Please see other Q&A: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54637795/how-to-make-a-tkinter-canvas-rectangle-transparent

Comment: Very clever! I wonder how this can be generalized to other shapes (transparent ovals, polygons, lines, text, etc). It is surprising that Tkinter is able to draw transparent images but other primitives aren't supported.

Comment: I posted an answer and pointed out how it isn't "true alpha".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot change the alpha of items on a canvas.

Comment: How do you _know_ this?  Where on earth is it documented?  Oh the frustration!

Comment: @MatthewWalker: I know it because no documentation says you can. The official tk documentation is very precise and complete, and nowhere does it mention alpha channels.

Comment: Thanks for that clarification.  That would make providing a source pretty difficult ;o)  Given that you can't do it natively in Tkinter, is there an alternative?  I was considering using Cairo to render an image that could be displayed in a Canvas.  Any better ideas?

Comment: @MatthewWalker, any success with that?

Comment: It can be done according to other answers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54637795/how-to-make-a-tkinter-canvas-rectangle-transparent

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix: no, that other answer shows how to simulate it using an image. You can't change the alpha of anything else on the canvas except images.

Comment: I've been using `stipple` tonight and it seems to work ok with canvas rectangle.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix, yes, using a stipple will simulate it, but it doesn’t change the alpha channel.

Answer (score 17):

I am not completely sure, but I think it is not possible to set a RGBA color as a fill color of a canvas item. However, you can give a try to the `stipple` option:

```
canvas.create_rectangle(20, 50, 300, 100, outline="black", fill="red", width=2, stipple="gray50")
```

Answer (score 5):

An idea is make a rectangle png image with semitransparent colors. Then use create_image instead of create_rectangle.

Comment: I'm late at the party, but wanted to confirm this: it works perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

You can't change the alpha but you can get simulated transparency with the `stipple` option in regular `tkinter`. For example using:

```
mycanvas.create_rectangle(X1, Y1, X2, Y2, fill=color, stipple="gray50")
```

yields:

[image: resize1.png]